# Multiple dynamic input add event jquery and call ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have dynamic multiple input inside table.

I want to add event on every id textbox, add event on every quantity too and call ajax. last, add event on subtotal when value change, add new row multiple input.

can you help me please?

[image]

```
<td><input type="text" maxlength="13" name="id[]" id="id" required></td>
<td><input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" readonly required></td>
<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" required></td>
<td><input type="text" name="price[]" id="price" readonly required></td>
<td><input type="text" name="subtotal[]" id="subtotal" readonly required></td>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id").each(function(index, item){
        $(item).on("change paste keyup", function(){
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({  
                dataType: 'json',
                url:"load_product.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{id:id},  
                success:function(data) {  
                    $('#name').val(data.name);
                    $('#price').val(data.price);
                }  
            });
        });
    });

    $("#quantity").on("change paste keyup", function(){
        var qty = $(this).val();
        var price = $('#price').val();
        var subtotal = qty * price;
        $('#subtotal').val(subtotal);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please rewrite this question using proper punctuation, paragraphs and show some code you already tried

Comment: `#id` should be unique, `$("#id").each(...)` could cause `selector` errors. Better to use classes `class="input-id", class="input-name", etc...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scribble shows two rows of input fields. If the *id* fields in both rows contain `id="id"` there is a possible problem: ids have to be *unique*. Better add a number to the id (e.g. `id="id1"`) or use `class` or [`data-`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) attributes.

If you furthermore want to add rows dynamically to your table you should use jQuery's [on function with the selector parameter](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler). Otherwise new elements will not be bound automatically to the event.

This is a possible solution using `data-` attributes including a button to insert new rows:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var groupCount = 0;
  
    String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
        var target = this;
        return target.split(search).join(replacement);
    };
  
    var rowTemplate = '<tr>'+
        '<td><input type="text" size="3" maxlength="13" name="id[]" data-group="%group%" data-id="id" required></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" size="3" name="name[]" data-group="%group%" data-id="name" readonly required></td>'+
         '<td><input type="text" size="3" name="quantity[]" data-group="%group%" data-id="quantity" required></td>'+
         '<td><input type="text" size="3" name="price[]" data-group="%group%" data-id="price" value="4" readonly required></td>'+
         '<td><input type="text" size="3" name="subtotal[]" data-group="%group%" data-id="subtotal" readonly required></td>'+
         '</tr>';
   
    for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
        groupCount++;
        $('#mytable tr:last').after(rowTemplate.replaceAll('%group%', groupCount));
    }
  
    $(document).on("change paste keyup", "input[data-id='id']", function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        var group = $(this).data('group');
     console.log('id:', id, group);
    });

    $(document).on("change paste keyup", "input[data-id='quantity']", function(){
        var qty = $(this).val();
        var group = $(this).data('group');
        var price = $("input[data-id='price'][data-group='"+group+"']").val();
        var subtotal = qty * price;
        $("input[data-id='subtotal'][data-group='"+group+"']").val(subtotal);
    });
  
    $("#btnadd").on('click', function() {
        groupCount++;
        $('#mytable tr:last').after(rowTemplate.replaceAll('%group%', groupCount));      
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
  <th>id</th>
  <th>name</th>
  <th>qty</th>
  <th>price</th>
  <th>subtotal</th>
</tr>
</table>
<button id="btnadd">New row</button>
```

Comment: Thanks sir, its work. next i want to add new row input dynamically, how to set increment data-group for new row sir?

Comment: @fadlihudaya I extended my snippet by a function to insert new rows. You have to keep track of the `data-group` by a global variable (e.g. `groupCount`).